# Reading and writing in firestore only through cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

I want to set my Cloud Firestore database permissions so that no one will be able to read and write from it except through Cloud Functions.

How can I do this?

My guess (according with Firestore docs) is that I have to set the right condition for what I want, but what condition would it be? I don't know how to "communicate" the cloud function call with the rules.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /<some_path>/ {
      allow read, write: if <some_condition>;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply eliminate all the rules and replace them with a rule that rejects everything:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

With nothing explicitly allowing mobile and web client access, none will be allowed.  The server SDKs always bypass security rules, so as long as the service account that you use to initialize the SDK has write access, it will work.  The default service account used in Cloud Functions should be fine.

Comment: I cannot write the way you did, it says `Line 3: The 'match' body must contain at least one declaration`.

Comment: Sorry, edited.  Just add a single rule that rejects all access to everything.

Comment: I always found these rules a bit obscure to understand, in the sense that I still don't know how to write specific conditions for each case. I'll still read about it, but meanwhile this seems good enough, thanks!

Comment: Yes, many people agree. We (the Firebase team) are working on better documentation and tutorials to help understand security rules better.